# Do we need a "best-practice" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed there are two dozen questions tagged "best-practice". I don't think that's a good tag, it doesn't mean anything. Shouldn't it be deleted?

PS: if a tag is deleted, how can be prevented that it's being used anew?

Comment: +1 for all those down votes. +1 for the ones who think down voting is same as answering "NO".

Comment: @hkBattousai  Up- and down-voting on meta means "I agree" or "I disagree".  On meta up- and down-voting has a different meaning, as compared to the main forum.  On meta, down-vote doesn't mean that something is grossly inadequate about the post.  So, pity up-vote skews the meta process, unless you actually agree with Johan.

Comment: Considering this question asks "do we need a best-practice

Answer (score 7):

[best-practice](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practice) is a worthwhile tag.  Let's keep it

Expressions "good engineering practice" and "best engineering practice" are commonly used in the industry.  These usually imply that diligence and fore-though was given to such aspects as:

- reliability
- uncommon operating conditions
- manufacturing variations
- future-proofing of the design

If an asker is using the [best-practice](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practice) tag, he is interested in these aspects, and not only in first principles.

Often, best practice is opposite to cutting corners or cost optimization.